# Какой предлог правильно использовать со словом "сервис", "в" или "на"?

Tags: предлоги

Примеры:

- Регистрация в/на сервисе Steam
- Поиск в/на картографическом сервисе
- Зайти в/на сервис по ремонту

Или есть варианты, где используется "в" и где "на"? От чего это зависит? Или оба варианты приемлемы, но какой-то более предпочтительнее?

Один преподаватель русского языка ответил, что "в". Попросить аргументировать не было времени.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Как различаются предлоги В и НА в общем случае**

Прелоги НА и В в русском языке имеют **обобщенную пространственную характеристику:** предлог В связывают с нахождением  внутри предмета (в столе, в стол), а предлог НА с нахождением на поверхности предмета (на столе, на стол).

Это различие учитывается **при переходе** от пространственных значений к другим значениям. Всё, что имеет **внутреннюю структуру, соотносится с предлогом В:** *пойти в магазин, учиться в институте.*

Всё, что **расположено на поверхности или имеет отвлеченное значение, связывают с предлогом НА**: *находиться на территории, купить на рынке, учиться на факультете*.

**2) Употребление предлогом со словом *сервис***

Слово ***сервис*** определяется как служба, оказывающая различные услуги, а также как само обслуживание.

**Если это реальный сервис,** например ремонт автомобилей, то здесь возможно употребление обоих предлогов: на сервисной станции, в сервисном центре (сравнить: на станции, в центре — это традиционное употребление В и НА).

**В сокращенном варианте это выглядит так**: *приехать на сервис (на сервисную станцию), **зайти на сервис по ремонту**, отвезти машину в сервис (в сервисный центр) или  на сервис (на сервисное обслуживание).* Частотность употребления этих форм сравнимы между собой.

На фирменном сервисе Renault. Здесь желательно использовать "отвлеченный" предлог НА, а не предлог В с более узким и конкретным значением.

**Если речь идет об информационной среде**, то там тоже можно использовать общие ориентиры при употреблении предлогов : искать в Сети, в Интернете, но разместить на сайте.

Здесь для слова ***сервис*** (сервисная служба) в общем случае предлог НА предпочтительнее, например: 100 миллионов видео скачивается на сервисе ежедневно. Из опроса в блоге авторов на сервисе «Livejournal».

Но когда ***сервис*** приобретает конкретность, то делается переход к предлогу В.

**3) Примеры**

**Регистрация на сервисе Steam, но регистрация в Steam.**

**Steam** – это крупнейший онлайн-магазин компьютерных игр, также Steam является и социальной сетью для геймеров.  В сеть или в онлайн-магазин заходят, поэтому **регистрация в Steam**, но: регистрация **на сервисе Steam** (как регистрация на любом сайте,  сохраняется предложное управление ***на сервисе***).

**Поиск на картографическом сервисе** (сохраняется предложное управление ***на сервисе***).

Answer (score 1):

Сервис - это учреждение, предоставляющие какие-л. услуги. Поэтому предлог в.

СЕРВИС, -а; м. [англ. service] Сфера обслуживания населения; совокупность учреждений по удовлетворению бытовых нужд и оказанию таких услуг. Служба сервиса. Гостиничный, автомобильный с. / Неодобр. О неудовлетворительной работе такой службы, отсутствии комфортных условий для отдыха, деятельности и т.п. С. хромает (разг.). Вот, он, наш с. 
Сервисный, -ая, -ое. С-ая служба. С-ые организации. С-ое обслуживание населения.

См: Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова (Грамота.ру).

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=+255481